# How do I initialize instance variables without having to put them in a constructor?

Tags: coffeescript

Given this

```
class A
   opt: {}
   init: (param) ->
      console.log "arg is ", @opt.arg
      @opt.arg = param

a = new A()
a.init("a")
console.log "first", a.opt.arg

b = new A()
b.init("b")
console.log "second", b.opt.arg
```

This is the output

```
arg is  undefined
first a
arg is  a
second b
```

The variable `opt` is acting as a static, it belongs to the class `A` instead of the instance `a` or `b`. How do I initialize instance variables without having to put them in a constructor? Like so:

```
class A
   constructor: ->
      @opt = {}
```

Edit:

This is problematic when inheritance is used since the super constructor is overwritten.

```
class B
   constructor: ->
      console.log "i won't happen"
class A extends B
   constructor: ->
      console.log "i will happen"
      @opt = {}
```

Comment: You initialize instance variables by putting them in the constructor so I guess the answer is "you don't".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your opt object is shared via the prototype, you can override it in instances directly, but if you change objects inside it, you actually change the prototype object (static like behavior). It's very important to understand prototypes when using coffeescript classes.

I think the best way to init instance members is in the constructor like you are doing atm.

Comment: Ok thank you for explaining. However using the constructor of initialization causes problems when inheritance is used. 
`class B
   constructor: ->
      console.log "i won't happen"
class A extends B
   constructor: ->
      console.log "i will happen"
      @opt = {}`

Comment: you can call `super` in the inherited constructor

Answer (score 1):

Ok so, initiation of all class members in the constructor and remembering to call `super()` in the subclass constructor solves it...

```
    class B
       constructor: ->
          console.log "i will also happen"
    class A extends B
       constructor: ->
          super()
          console.log "i will happen"
          @opt = {}

    new A()
```

Answer (score 0):

If "opt" should act as a static attach it to the class

```
class A
    @opt: {}
    init: (param) ->
        # the rest is ommitted
```

Comment: Apparently Simon _doesn't_ want it to act as a static, yet not initialize it in the constructor...